# Can you recommend me a book about the history of complex analysis?

Tags: complex-analysis, book-recommendation, math-history

I am writing an article about the beauty of complex analysis and need some chronological details. Is there any particular book where I can read and learn about the topic?

Comment: I would check out the notes in Remmert two books on the topic (Theory of Complex Functions and its more advanced sequel Classical Topics in Complex Function Theory); lots of historical development and biographical stuff about people who developed the theory

Comment: Is there a branch of complex analysis you intend to write about? It's a relatively large field with a rich history, so answers could differ drastically based on what you intend to write about

Comment: the word you were looking for is chronological

Comment: @Conrad wow! this will do. thank you for the comment

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I have the total freedom to select which area I want to write :) HOPE after some reading, I will be able to pick an interesting topic...

Comment: @WillJagy finally :/

Comment: happy to be of help; for example on page 49 in Remmert I (TCF) we learn that actually, the Cauchy-Riemann equations occur in D'Alembert's work in 1752 and also in Euler and Lagrange, while in 1814 Cauchy noticed that they essentially define complex analyticity but did not build the theory based on them, and Riemann was the first to build the theory of complex functions based on them starting in 1847, so the name...

Comment: The relatively recent books by the great Barry Simon (volume 2a and 2b)  have many historical notes, as well as the material for a good year in Complex Analysis.

Comment: Maybe Jeremy Gray's [The Real and the Complex: A History of Analysis in the 19th Century](https://smile.amazon.com/Real-Complex-Analysis-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/3319237144/)?

Comment: Thank you all for your recommendations

Comment: *Mathematics and Its History*, 3rd edition, by Stillwell includes three chapters on complex numbers and their functions.

Comment: Wolfram Koepf has a great 27 page paper summarizing thr history of the proof of the Bieberbach Conjecture, which I was reading through yesterday when I remembered this question. I'm not sure who your audience is, but if an elegant mix of differential equations with hypergeometric function theory with power series inequalities is within the scope then I would highly recommend the article.